# Почему не работает скрипт?

Tags: curl, php

```
<?php

define('EMAIL', '7280892b4f@mail.ru');//логин
define('PASS', '123456');  //пароль
define('COOKIES',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cook.txt');//файл для записи COOKIES при авторизации

/* Пример: */
if(vksms(123456, 'Паниковский вас всех продаст, купит и снова продаст…но уже дороже'))
    echo 'Message send to user id 123456';
else
    echo 'Error ?';
/* конец примера */

/**
 *
 * @param int $to_id
 * @param string $message
 * @param string $title
 * @return bool
 */
function vksms($to_id,$message,$title='')
{
    $auth = vksms_curl('http://login.vk.com/?act=login', '&email=' . EMAIL . '&pass=' . PASS . '&expire=&vk=', 'http://vkontakte.ru/');
    $Page = vksms_curl('http://vkontakte.ru/id1');

    if (preg_match('#chas: cur\.decodehash\(\'([^\']+)#i', $Page, $matches))
    {
        $chas = strrev(substr($matches[1],4,13)) . strrev(substr($matches[1],20,25));

        $send = iconv('cp1251', 'utf-8', vksms_curl(
                                'http://vkontakte.ru/al_mail.php',
                                'act=a_send&ajax=1&al=1&chas=' . $chas . '&from=box&message=' . urlencode($message) . '&title=' . urlencode($title) . '&to_id=' . $to_id)
        );
        return preg_match('|Сообщение отправлено|ui', $send);
    }
    else
        return FALSE;
}

//функция для работы с cURL
function vksms_curl($url,$post='',$ref='',$basicAuth=':',$userAgent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090824 Firefox/3.5.4',$headers=FALSE)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,$headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$userAgent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'utf-8');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,999);

    if($post)
    {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    }
    if(defined('COOKIES'))
    {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, COOKIES);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIES);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $basicAuth);

    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}?>
```

Почему не работает скрипт? По идее все верно.

Вот изменил не много все равно не работает
      <?php
    define('EMAIL', '**********');//логин
    define('PASS', '****************');  //пароль
    define('COOKIES',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cook.txt');//файл для записи COOKIES при авторизации

```
$post = array(
            'act' => 'login',
             'email' => EMAIL,
            'pass' => PASS,
            'pda' => '1',
            'to' => '',
             'from_host' => 'm.vkontakte.ru');

    $auth = vksms_curl('http://login.vk.com/?act=login', $post, 'http://vkontakte.ru/');
 $Page = vksms_curl('http://vkontakte.ru/id19685573');

    if (preg_match('#chas: cur\.decodehash\(\'([^\']+)#i', $Page, $matches))
    {
        $message='22222';
        $to_id='19685573';
        $title='';
        $chas = strrev(substr($matches[1],4,13)) . strrev(substr($matches[1],20,25));
        $send = iconv('cp1251', 'utf-8', vksms_curl(
                                'http://vkontakte.ru/al_mail.php',
                                'act=a_send&ajax=1&al=1&chas=' . $chas . '&from=box&message=' . urlencode($message) . '&title=' . urlencode($title) . '&to_id=' . $to_id)
        );   echo $send;
        echo preg_match('|Сообщение отправлено|ui', $send);
    }

//функция для работы с cURL
function vksms_curl($url,$post='',$ref='',$basicAuth=':',$userAgent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090824 Firefox/3.5.4',$headers=FALSE)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,$headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$userAgent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'utf-8');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,999);

    if($post)
    {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    }
    if(defined('COOKIES'))
    {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, COOKIES);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIES);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $basicAuth);

    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}?>
```

Comment: нада смотреть) мне щас больше перл по душе для ботов)

Comment: Кому как)

Comment: Не работает? Что не работает? Где не работает? Как не работает? По мне так работает XD

Comment: Уточните что именно не работает, какие ошибку и в какой строке выдает?

Comment: Error ? выходит и все. Значит в функций  vksms проблема

Comment: блин, 5 раз прочитал. "Всё овет равно понял не" ...

Comment: хз

Answer (score 4):

Основная проблема Вашего скрипта в том, что Вы не проверяете результат выполнения вызываемых функций. Соответственно невозможно понять, где ошибка. Ну результат curl_setopt проверять может быть и не надо, хотя для CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE я бы результат проверил. А вот результат curl_exec проверить надо обязательно, и если что-то не так, вывести диагностическое сообщение.

На предмет собственно ошибок меня смутили следующие вещи:

- Символ '&' в начале строки $post.
- Работа с COOKIE. Вы уверены, что указав CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE можно успокоиться? А он новые значения туда запишет? Разумно предположить, что эта функция только читает указанный файл, но никак не записывает туда результат авторизации. У Вас этот файл на диске есть? Что в нем было до запуска скрипта? После завершения?
- А у скрипта есть права на запись файла в DOCUMENT_ROOT?

Еще один совет: если Вы не знаете, в каком месте скрипта происходит ошибка, следует добавить кучу строк echo "сообщениеn"; между рабочими командами. Так Вы хоть узнаете, до какой строки доходит выполнение скрипта до ошибки.

Comment: *Так я же не array отправляю чтобы post это на счет символа '&'
* Да права есть
Хорошо щас проверим

Comment: Символ '&' разделяет параметры в строке post, а у Вас строка post с этого символа начинается.